# how to format the content of a html cell

Tags: html, html-table, word-wrap

I have a html table, and I would like to populate with an icon that should be aligned on the left and text that should be aligned on the right.

I have tried this : http://jsfiddle.net/vLpazdf7/

However:

- seems not very clean to use `<p style="text-align:left` for the image but `<span style="float:right;">` for the text? Is there a more elegant way?
- When the entire table doesn't fit the window, it wraps, hence the image and the corresponding text are not anymore on the same line, despite the `nowrap` I put on each cell.

Comment: You could `float: left` the image and `text-align: right` for the rest? Or put the image in a separate cell? That would be safest.

Comment: also its bad practice to write inline css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a couple ideas depending on what exactly you're trying to achieve - one way is to use divs inside each table cell, like this:

```
<td>
   <div class="container">
       <div class="left">
           <img src="http://dummyimage.com/26x13/00b32d/fafaff.png&amp;text=+">
       </div>
       <div class="right"><span>This text is on the left</span>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
       <div class="left">
           <img src="http://dummyimage.com/21x13/00b32d/fafaff.png&amp;text=+">
       </div>
       <div class="right"><span>Other text on the left</span>
       </div>
   </div>
</td>
```

And using CSS classes to manipulate them:

```
.left {
    width: 26px;
    float: left;
}
.right {
    padding-left: 28px;
    text-align: right;
}
.container {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Result: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toc4pbxt/3/) ([full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/toc4pbxt/3/embedded/result/))

---

Another way would be to keep things as they are (with the inline code stripped out) and add a class to the table:

```
<table class="test-table">
```

...

```
<td>
    <p>
       <img src="http://dummyimage.com/26x13/00b32d/fafaff.png&amp;text=+">
       <span>This text is on the left</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/21x13/00b32d/fafaff.png&amp;text=+">
        <span>Other text on the left</span>
    </p>
</td>
```

And using CSS like this:

```
.test-table > tbody > tr > td > p {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}

.test-table > tbody > tr > td > p > img {
    display: inline-block;

}

.test-table > tbody > tr > td > p > span {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Result: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o64muts4/1/) ([full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/o64muts4/1/embedded/result/))

---

EDIT: Or you could use `<ul>`:

```
<td>
    <ul class="test-ul">
        <li class="first-image"><span>This text is on the left</span></li>
        <li class="second-image"><span>Other text on the left</span></li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.test-ul {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}

.test-ul > .first-image {
    list-style-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/26x13/00b32d/fafaff.png&amp;text=+');
}

.test-ul > .second-image {
    list-style-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/21x13/00b32d/fafaff.png&amp;text=+');
}

.test-ul > .third-image {
    list-style-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/1x13/f00c3a/fafaff.png&amp;text=+');
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/o64muts4/2/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <table border="1" style="font-size: small; font-family: 'Arial'">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <th>  </th>
     <th> column A </th>
     <th> column A </th>
     <th> column A </th>
     <th> column A </th>
     <th> column A </th>
     <th> column A </th>
     <th> column A </th>
     <th> column A </th>
     <th> column B </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td align="right"> Row 1 </td>
     <td nowrap="">
        <p style="text-align:left;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="Desert.jpg" width="20" height="30"> <span style="text-align:right;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">This text is on the left</span></p>
        <p style="text-align:left;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="Desert.jpg" width="20" height="30"> <span style="text-align:right;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">Other text on the left</span></p>

     </td>
     <td nowrap="">
        <p style="text-align:left;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/26x13/00b32d/fafaff.png&amp;text=+"> <span style="text-align:right;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">This text is on the left</span></p>
        <p style="text-align:left;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/21x13/00b32d/fafaff.png&amp;text=+"> <span style="text-align:right;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">Other text on the left</span></p>

     </td>
     <td nowrap="">
        <p style="text-align:left;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/26x13/00b32d/fafaff.png&amp;text=+"> <span style="text-align:right;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">This text is on the left</span></p>
        <p style="text-align:left;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/21x13/00b32d/fafaff.png&amp;text=+"> <span style="text-align:right;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">Other text on the left</span></p>

     </td>
     <td nowrap="">
        <p style="text-align:left;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/26x13/00b32d/fafaff.png&amp;text=+"> <span style="text-align:right;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">This text is on the left</span></p>
        <p style="text-align:left;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/21x13/00b32d/fafaff.png&amp;text=+"> <span style="text-align:right;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">Other text on the left</span></p>

     </td>
     <td nowrap="">
        <p style="text-align:left;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/26x13/00b32d/fafaff.png&amp;text=+"> <span style="text-align:right;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">This text is on the left</span></p>
        <p style="text-align:left;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/21x13/00b32d/fafaff.png&amp;text=+"> <span style="text-align:right;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">Other text on the left</span></p>

     </td>
     <td nowrap="">
        <p style="text-align:left;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/26x13/00b32d/fafaff.png&amp;text=+"> <span style="text-align:right;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">This text is on the left</span></p>
        <p style="text-align:left;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/21x13/00b32d/fafaff.png&amp;text=+"> <span style="text-align:right;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">Other text on the left</span></p>

     </td>
     <td nowrap="">
        <p style="text-align:left;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/26x13/00b32d/fafaff.png&amp;text=+"> <span style="text-align:right;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">This text is on the left</span></p>
        <p style="text-align:left;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/21x13/00b32d/fafaff.png&amp;text=+"> <span style="text-align:right;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">Other text on the left</span></p>

     </td>
     <td nowrap="">
        <p style="text-align:left;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/26x13/00b32d/fafaff.png&amp;text=+"> <span style="text-align:right;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">This text is on the left</span></p>
        <p style="text-align:left;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/21x13/00b32d/fafaff.png&amp;text=+"> <span style="text-align:right;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">Other text on the left</span></p>

     </td>
     <td nowrap="">
        <p style="text-align:left;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/1x13/f00c3a/fafaff.png&amp;text=+">  <span style="text-align:right;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">Text</span></p>
        <p style="text-align:left;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/1x13/f00c3a/fafaff.png&amp;text=+">  <span style="text-align:right;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">Text</span></p>
        <p style="text-align:left;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/1x13/f00c3a/fafaff.png&amp;text=+">  <span style="text-align:right;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">Text</span></p>
        <p style="text-align:left;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/1x13/f00c3a/fafaff.png&amp;text=+">  <span style="text-align:right;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">Text</span></p>
     </td>

   </tr>
 </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: what would be the proper CSS equivalent? To avoid repeating the `margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px` everywhere?